# iOS app does not change to RTL language

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization

I want to test my iOS app in right-to-left layout on device. When I set "Edit Scheme > Application Language > Right-To-Left Pseudo Language" in Xcode and run on device, the layout is flipped to RTL. However, if I leave "System language" in Xcode and then change the system language to Hebrew in iPhone settings (General > Language and region > iPhone language > Hebrew) my app is not displayed in RTL mode (all other apps do).

Why isn't my app layout changed to RTL when I change the iPhone's language to Hebrew?

I'm using Xcode 8.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what the problem was. I needed to add the Hebrew language internationalization in Project > Info section. After I re-ran on device, all layout appeared flipped (that is, in the right-to-left layout).

Comment: Any other tricks here @Evgenii? I tried your suggestion in Xcode 9.2 and am still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it is text alignment please try the following

First try getting layout direction by

```
if ([UIView userInterfaceLayoutDirectionForSemanticContentAttribute:view.semanticContentAttribute] == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft) {

}
```

Then set the text alignment as follows.

```
enter code here
[[(NSMutableParagraphStyle *)paraStyle setAlignment:NSNaturalTextAlignment];
```